# JavaScript Table isn't showing on screen

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I'm trying to create a little store but I can't seem to get my shopping cart to work. I want the user to be able to press a shopping bag icon and get a list of what is in their shopping cart. If they want, they can delete the object out of the shopping cart. However, I'm stuck because it won't load the items into the shopping cart. Will someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

js:

```
    function showWinkelmandje() {
        console.log("winkelmandje.onclicked;");
        console.log(document.getElementById("winkelmandje_knop"));
        //Winkelmandje aan- of uitzetten
        if(document.getElementById("winkelmandje_knop").checked) {
            document.getElementById("winkelmandje").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("rijen").style.visibility = "visible";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("winkelmandje").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("rijen").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        var rijen = "<table><th>Titel</th><th>Artiest</th>" + "<th>Genre</th><th>Prijs</th><th>Aantal</th><th>Delete</th>";
        var rij = "";
        var lus = document.getElementById("lus").value;
        for(var x=0; x<lus; x++) {
            if(document.getElementById("aantal["+ x +"]").value==0) continue;
            rij="<tr>";
            titel = document.getElementById("titel["+ x +"]").value;
            artiest = document.getElementById("artiest["+ x +"]").value;
            genre = document.getElementById("genre["+ x +"]").value;
            prijs = document.getElementById("prijs["+ x +"]").value;
            aantal = document.getElementById("aantal["+ x +"]").value;
            rij += "<td width='120'>" + titel + "</td>" + 
                    "<td>" + artiest + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + genre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + prijs + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + aantal + "</td>" +
                    "<td onclick='deleterij(" + x + ");'>&#10008;</td></tr>";
            rijen += rij;
        }
        rijen += "</table";
        document.getElementById("rijen").innerHTML =  rijen;
    }
    function deleterij(id){
        verwijder = confirm("Wil je " + document.getElementById("titel[" +id+"]").value + " verwijderen?");
        if(verwijder) {
            document.getElementById("aantal["+ id + "]").value = 0;
            showWinkelmandje();
        }
    }


php:

    <?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION["ID"])&&($_SESSION["STATUS"]!="ACTIEF")) {
        echo "<script>alert('U heeft geen toegang tot de pagina'); location.href='../index.php';</script>";
    }
    ?>
    <!-- dit is het zoek formulier -->
<!-- this is where the searchbar is -->
    <script src="js/webshop.js"></script>
    <div class="content">
        <form name="search" id="search" action="" method="POST">
            <div style="background-color: #C2F98E; height: 25px; margin-top: 5%; padding: 0;">
            <input type="text" style="float: left; width: 70%;" id="patroon" name="patroon" placeholder="Zoek albums"/>
            <input type="submit" style="float: none; width: 10%; font-size: 1.2rem;" id="zoeken" value="&#128269;" /><br>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    // this is where I'm trying to make the search bar dynamic however it doesnt seem to want to search my albums
        //Hier wordt de sql opdracht gegenereerd
        if(isset($_POST["zoeken"])&& !empty($_POST["patroon"])) {
            $patroon = htmlspecialchars($_POST["patroon"]);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM album WHERE titel LIKE '%$patroon%' || artiest LIKE '%$patroon%' || genre LIKE '%$patroon%'";
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM album LIMIT 3";
        }
    ?>
    <div class="content">
    <form name="webshop" id="webshop" action="index.php?page=bestellen" method="POST">
    <?php
    // Dit is het bestel formulier met albums uit de db
        $stmt = $verbinding->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $albums = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $lus = 0;
        foreach($albums as $album) {
            echo "<img width='100px' src='img/". $album['cover']."'/>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$lus]' id='id[$lus]' value'".$album['ID']. "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='titel[$lus]' id='titel[$lus]' value'".$album['titel']. "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='artiest[$lus]' id='artiest[$lus]' value'".$album['artiest']. "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='genre[$lus]' id='genre[$lus]' value'".$album['genre']. "' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='prijs[$lus]' id='prijs[$lus]' value'".$album['prijs']. "' />";
            echo "<br> titel:". $album["titel"] . "prijs: " . $album["prijs"];
            echo "<br> Voorraad:". $album["voorraad"];
            echo "<br>Aantal:";
            echo "<input class='aantal' type='text' style='width: 10%; name='aantal[$lus]' id='aantal[$lus]' value='0' />";
            echo "<hr />";
            $lus++;
    
        }
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='lus' id='lus' value'".$lus."'/>";
    ?>
<!-- this is the shooping cart-->
    <!--winkelmandje aan- en uitzetten -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="winkelmandje_knop" id="winkelmandje_knop" onclick="javascript:showWinkelmandje();" class="icon" value=&#128717;/>
    <label for="winkelmandje_knop">&#128717;</label>
    <br>
        <div class="icon_container">
            <input type="submit" class="icon" id="submit" name="submit" value="&rarr;" />
        </div>
    <br>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!--winkelmandje-->
    <div id="winkelmandje">
         <div id="rijen"></div>
         <input type="checkbox" id="winkelmandje_knop" onclick="javascript:showWinkelmandje();" class="icon" value="X" />
         <label for="winkelmandje_knop" style="color: red;">&#8861;</label>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Additional Information**

as you see here it doesnt show the tables information

[image]

Comment: Typo: `rijen += "</table";` is missing  the `>` at the end.

Comment: ah thank you but sadly it doesnt fix anything

Comment: After you build the table it doesn't look like you're ever making it visible again, I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do but do you need to reset the visibility to visible at the end of the function?
document.getElementById("rijen").style.visibility = "visible";

Comment: no what your seeing there is: if winkelmandje is clicked then document.getElementById("winkelmandje").style.visibility = "visible";  and document.getElementById("rijen").style.visibility = "visible"; and the else to invisible means if you havent clicked on the shooping bag it won't show up. To say it easier if check box is checked show the winkelmandje

Comment: i feel like it has problems in the loop as it does show the tables names but it refuses to show that I put in the chart

Comment: You may need to wrap the ```<th>```s with ```<tr>```.

Comment: Your inputs are missing `=` here `value='".$album['ID']. "'` same for all other inputs .